# Sqlite - combining 2 SELECT statements from same table

Tags: sqlite

I need to combine 2 results from `SELECT` statements that look in the same table.

What I have works but I'm sure there is a better way to do it.

```
SELECT  
    games._id,win.winner,deal.dealer
FROM
    games,
    (SELECT 
         players.name as winner
     FROM 
         games, players
     WHERE 
         players._id = games.winner 
         AND  games._id = 2) AS win,
    (SELECT 
         players.name as dealer
     FROM  
         games, players
     WHERE 
         players._id = games.dealer 
         AND  games._id = 2) AS deal
WHERE 
    games._id = 2
```

Thanks for your help optimizing this query.

EDIT:

The schema for the tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE games 
(
     _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     winner integer, 
     dealer integer
)

CREATE TABLE players 
(
     _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
     name text
)
```

Comment: This query is going to be hard to analyze without a proper look at your database schema.  You should include that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below(untested code) should work:

```
SELECT  g._id,p1.name AS winner,p2.name AS dealer
FROM games AS g join players AS p1 ON p1._id = g.winner 
JOIN players AS p2 on p2._id = g.dealer
WHERE g._id = 2
```

Comment: I test it but it didn't work; no such column: p1.winner: SELECT  g._id,p1.winner,p2.dealer
FROM games AS g join players AS p1 ON p1._id = g.winner 
JOIN players AS p2 on p2._id = g.dealer
WHERE g._id = 2

Comment: My bad! I modified my query. Please check now.